# Disqus: how to customize counters

Tags: html, css, disqus

I am trying to customize the disqus comments count in my blog page http://www.lowcoupling.com
the problem is although, as you can see, I have manage to remove the word Comment(s) I can't see how to disable/remove the reactions count. 
Is there any way to do that? I can't find it in the settings page

Comment: We just removed the reactions text as well, so this should solve your question with no extra work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Disqus admin and add the HTML tags there like so:

```
Zero Comments      | 0<span style="display:none;">
One Comment        | 1<span style="display:none;">
Multiple Comments  | {num}<span style="display:none;">

Zero Reactions     | 0 Reactions</span>
One Reaction       | 1 Reaction</span>
Multiple Reactions | {num} Reactions</span>
```

Comment: There isn't any Reactions section in the admin page